# How to query for "all but one" in graphite/grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm playing with grafana and I want to create a panel where I compare data from one app server against the average of all the others except that one. Something like:

```
apps.machine1.someMetric
averageSeries(apps.*.not(machine1).someMetric)
```

Can that be done? How?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sounds like you want to filter a seriesList, you an do that inclusively using the 'grep' function or exclusively using the 'exclude' function

```
exclude(apps.machine*.someMetric,"machine1")
```

and pass that into averageSeries

```
averageSeries(exclude(apps.machine*.someMetric,"machine1"))
```

You can read more about those functions here:
http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.exclude

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it filters out whatever it is you do not want to include. Got my vote :)

Comment: I didn't see a reference to what type of regex you can use in the `pattern` argument to `exclude`, but to exclude multiple terms you can use something like: `exclude(seriesList, "first|second")`

Answer (score 6):

After reading the [Graphite URL API docs section about wildcard paths](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html#paths-and-wildcards) I don't think there is any "all but one" target query. However if you don't have many machines you can list all them but the excluded one in your query:

```
apps.machine1.someMetric
averageSeries(apps.{machine2,machine3,machine4,machine5}.someMetric)
```

Or use a character range:

```
apps.machine1.someMetric
averageSeries(apps.machine[2-5].someMetric)
```